# Method channel not work in Flutter Module

Tags: android, methods, flutter, channel

I write demo code in flutter dev doc to show battery level.
But code not work, Method channel show log error when call:
- Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getBatteryLevel on channel samples.flutter.dev/battery)
Please help me! Thank all!

Comment: Please include the code that you're using to call the method channel, and the code you've written in Java/Kotlin on the android side to handle the call. And double check that you're registering for the same method channel on both sides and handling the right function name.

Comment: @rmtmckenzie I checked all code and it same as the example, it working well in Flutter app but not work in flutter module.

Comment: So you've moved the code from an app to a module - are you using it as a plugin? Do you register a method channel on the android side? Without code or at the very least a full description of what you've done we can't help you. But make sure that you're making a MethodChannel with name "sample.flutter.dev/battery" and calling result.success for the call.method "getBatteryLevel" on the android side. You'd normally make the MethodChannel in a static `registerWith` function for a plugin or in your MainActivity's onCreate.

Comment: @rmtmckenzie I embbed code flutter into exists native android app as 'flutter module'. In my Project: MyApp2 is native app, my_flutter_2 is a flutter module and here my link source code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rD-3upjGFNS-i3c8p1fWqgq5fG0ih14p/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using cached flutter engine in your native app.

Your application class should set FlutterPluginCache.

```
class Application : MultiDexApplication() {
    lateinit var flutterEngine : FlutterEngine

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        // Instantiate a FlutterEngine.
        flutterEngine = FlutterEngine(this)

        // Start executing Dart code to pre-warm the FlutterEngine.
        flutterEngine.dartExecutor.executeDartEntrypoint(
                DartExecutor.DartEntrypoint.createDefault()
        )

        // Cache the FlutterEngine to be used by FlutterActivity.
        FlutterEngineCache
                .getInstance()
                .put("flutter_engine_id", flutterEngine)
    }
}
```

In your app's activity, get the flutter engine and set method call handler.

```
 class FlutterDemoActivity : FlutterActivity() {
      private val CHANNEL = "samples.flutter.dev/battery"
      private val flutter_engine_id = "flutter_engine_id"

      @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
      override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_flutter_demo)
        
        //Get your flutter engine using engine id. 
        val engine = FlutterEngineCache.getInstance().get(flutter_engine_id)
        engine?.let{
          //Set method call handler to that engine.
          MethodChannel(it.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, 
          CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler {
             call, result ->
             if(call.method=="getBatteryLevel"){
               result.success(89) //send whatever you need here.
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there are no details about the code, I am assuming that you are passing the correct method name along with the correct channel name. Make sure that the FlutterActivity in your android native code is not destroyed at any point in time. Method Channels use flutter engine to invoke android native code, which will no longer be present in case your FlutterActivity has been destroyed.